# ConTeXt : very strange behavior with placefigure

Tags: floats, context

While trying to typeset a document with ConTeXt, I came across the problem you can see on the following MWE.

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A5]
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=4cm]
\starttext
%% Works correctly
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
here is a test : \input linden
\hairline
%% Wrapping doesn't work
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
{here is a test :} \input linden    
\stoptext
```

[image]

I don't understand how this can happen. Is there an explanation and, if possible, a workaround ?

Comment: You are putting the start of the paragraph in a group (with the braces), that's a problem if the code wants to do some \everypar magic or something like this. Start the paragraph with `\dontleavehmode`

Comment: Ok, it works. Can you make an answer out of your explanation so that I can accept the answer please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

The start of the paragraph after the figure must not occur in a group.  Either remove the braces or start the paragraph explicitly by prefixing `\dontleavehmode`.

#### Explanation

When using the cutout placement method, ConTeXt does some bookkeeping.  It remembers where the graphic was placed and how much space it will occupy.  The next paragraphs will then be adjusted with the correct `\parshape`.  To know whether a paragraph has to be adjusted ConTeXt retrieves some information, such as the placement of cutout figures when a new paragraph starts.

TeX defines the starting of a new paragraph as switching from vertical to horizontal mode.  This happens when TeX reads a character.  At this point the contents of `\everypar` are inserted where ConTeXt stored the float information.

This is where grouping comes in.  In your example the paragraph starts with

```
{here is a test :} The warm water...
```

Remember, that a paragraph is started when *a character* is encountered.  Because the first character is the `h` of `here`, the paragraph starts inside a group.  That means, that the contents of `\everypar` are also inserted inside the group and TeX will forget about everything that was set inside the group which was not done `\global`.  Unfortunately, the float is marked as *checked* globally, but the `\parshape` will be forgotten when TeX exits the group.

#### Advice

Never start a paragraph with a group unless you know the implications.